# How do I fix this Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am working on a code for class but I keep getting a -- Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction -- error where it says cout << void enterStolenMoonPies(int* array, int numDays) << endl; but I don't understand how to fix it? Is it how I formatted it or is it a problem with the actual function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Moonpie.h"
//#include "Functions.cpp"

using namespace std;

int* makeArray(int days);
void enterStolenMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);
int* totalMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);
float averageMoonPies(int numDays, int sum);
int* highestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);
int* lowestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);


int main()
{

    int days;

    cout <<"How many days did Jane steal moon pies?: ";
    cin >> days;

    cout << "Enter the number of moon pies stolen each day:";
    cout << void enterStolenMoonPies(int* array, int numDays) << endl;

    cout << "---------Results--------------"<< endl;

    cout << "Total number of Moon Pies stolen: ";
    int* totalMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

    cout << "Average number of Moon Pies stolen per day: ";
    float averageMoonPies(int numDays, int sum);

    cout << "Highest amount of Moon Pies stolen in a day: ";
    int* highestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

    cout << "Lowest amount of Moon Pies stolen in a day: ";
    int* lowestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

}
```

This is the header:

```
#ifndef Moonpie_h
#define Moonpie_h

int* makeArray(int days);

void enterStolenMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

int* totalMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

float averageMoonPies(int numDays, int sum);

int* highestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

int* lowestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays);

#endif /* Moonpie_h */
```

And this is the Functions file:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "Moonpie.cpp"



using namespace std;

int* makeArray(int days)
{
    int* numDays = new int[days];

    return numDays;
}



void enterStolenMoonPies(int* array, int numDays)
{
    int stolenMP = 0;

    for(int i =0; i<numDays; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of moon pies stolen each day:" << endl;
        cout << "Day " << i << ": ";
        cin >> stolenMP;
    }
}



int* totalMoonPies(int* array, int numDays)
{
    int* sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numDays; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}




float averageMoonPies(int numDays, int sum)
{
    float average;
    average = static_cast<float>(sum)/numDays;

    return average;
}




int* highestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays)
{
    int* highest;
    highest = &array[0];

    for(int i = 0; i <= numDays; i++)
        if (&array[i] > highest)
            highest = &array[i];

    return highest;
}



int* lowestMoonPies(int* array, int numDays)
{
    int* lowest;
    lowest = &array[0];

    for(int i = 0; i <= numDays; i++)
        if (&array[i] < lowest)
            lowest = &array[i];

    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like you are guessing how the language works. I suggest you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: You need to lookup "how to call a function". More importantly, why is Jane stealing all the moonpies?

Comment: imho the best answer you can get here is: start from scratch by writing line by line only adding the next one if you understood the last and only if it compiles.

Comment: Hint:  You are not assigning the return values of the functions to variables.  (You are duplicating the function declarations).

Answer (score 0):

As in comments, your code is not correct in many ways.
Your functions should not be declared twice (you have one in header an one in your source) but this is only one problem out of many.

```
cout << "Enter the number of moon pies stolen each day:";
cout << void enterStolenMoonPies(int* array, int numDays) << endl;
```

will not work.
It should be at least

```
cout << "Enter the number of moon pies stolen each day:";
cout << enterStolenMoonPies(array, numDays) << endl;
```

delete all the function declarations befor your main and include the corresponding header file.

You better start again with a simple program and overthink to use these pointers for your start as it is more complicated.